# Closure inside Function

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

[image: Code snippet]

I'm trying to create a calculator using closures and functions. I got until the actual calculation function which takes in two values, then the user can select which operator to use (addition, multiplication, etc). I don't know how to actually return the value of that calculation.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure is, effectively, a function and you simply invoke it as such.

```
return operator(numberOne:valueOne, numberTwo:valueTwo)
```